# store multiple checkbox values to database using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I want to store the multiple checkbox values to store in a single field. I use that link http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Storing-array-data-to-MySQL-using-PHP-1296.php. But i dont get the result.Give Help to find that problem.

Comment: What result *do* you get?

Comment: what result is getting inserted?

Comment: Can you post your code so we that we can check where's the problem?

Comment: show us your checkbox code please

Comment: I want to display the selected checkbox values andall the values must be stored in the single field itself.

Comment: what is the datatype of column..

Comment: <form action="index1.php" method="post">
 
<input type="checkbox" id="things[]" value="red"> Cat
<input type="checkbox" id="things[]" value="blue"> Mouse
<input type="checkbox" id="things[]" value="green"> Car
<input type="checkbox" id="things[]" value="yellow"> DaniWeb

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>This is my checkbox code..

Comment: $fruit= implode(", ", $_POST['fruit']);


foreach($_POST['fruit'] as $fruit) 
{ 
    echo $fruit;
}

Comment: I tried the above..ITS NOT WORKING..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your column as 'set' (specify the all possible values.) data type and than run the below query.

```
$comma_separated = implode(",", $values);
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(col_name) VALUES('$comma_separated')";
$result_insert = mysql_query($insert_query);
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will helpful

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="red" />Red</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="blue" />Blue</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="orange" />orange</p>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="sub" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Server Could not be connected");
    mysql_select_db("gobinath") or die("database connection problam");
    $color=implode(',',$_POST['color']);

    mysql_query("insert into mcheck values('','$color')") or die("insert problam");

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```