# store the checkbox value using set type

Tags: php, mysql, set

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [store multiple checkbox values to database using php and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039190/store-multiple-checkbox-values-to-database-using-php-and-mysql)

How to store the checkbox values to single field by using the set column type using php and mysql. Is it possible?

My Code:

```
<?php
$genre = serialize($_POST['genre']);
$query = "INSERT INTO myset(genre) values('" . $genre . "')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Its not working.

Comment: I want to store the multiple values in a single column field..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="2">..
```

PHP

```
<?php
$genre= @implode(',', $_POST['genre']);
$query = "INSERT INTO myset(genre) values('$genre')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

After this, you will find value '1,2' in your (single) genre column.

Comment: Ya..Thank you very much..Its working nice..

Comment: Yw.. and yea I love that PHP "feature" too. Enjoy:P